# Getting NaN as my first value for value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a small dataset on which I need to perform a counting value operation. The dataset looks something like this:

```
A   B
1   67
1   56
1   23
2   22
2   12
3   78

columns = ["Count"]
g = pd.DataFrame(A.value_counts(), index=False, columns=columns)
```

So what I wanted to do was try and count the number of instances of every unique value in column A and create a new DataFrame, I tried it using `A.value_counts()`, but when I try putting in this new column I get the first value as NaN. What can be the issue? This is what I get:

```
A Count
1  NaN
2  3
3  2
```

I am getting the first value as NaN after which the normal output is displayed. What can be the reason? I want the output to be something like this:

```
A  Count
1   3
2   2
3   1
```

How should I avoid getting this NaN value? The indexing in the dataset starts with 0.

Comment: Can you share the code that produced the result?

Comment: Yes, an MCVE please: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would normally do

```
In [2334]: df.A.value_counts().reset_index(name='Count').rename(columns={'index': 'A'})
Out[2334]:
   A  Count
0  1      3
1  2      2
2  3      1
```

Or,

```
In [2335]: df.groupby('A').size().reset_index(name='Count')
Out[2335]:
   A  Count
0  1      3
1  2      2
2  3      1
```

Details

```
In [2337]: df
Out[2337]:
   A   B
0  1  67
1  1  56
2  1  23
3  2  22
4  2  12
5  3  78
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing us with any code, but this little bit might prove to be useful:

```
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

with open('data', 'r') as datafile:
    datafile.readline()  # skipping the header
    for line in datafile:
        value = line.split()[0]  # assuming whitespace is a delimiter
        counts[value] = counts[value] + 1
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh, wait, you're using pandas. Sorry, glanced over that. I can remove my answer if needed.